# Python - Determine if Item is in a List Using a Function

Tags: python, list, function, boolean

I'm trying to write a function in Python to determine whether or not an item is in a list. I've been trying variations of this code.

No matter how I try it, it always returns a FALSE Boolean value. Even if I put the print commands inside the functions, it only prints with the results for a false value. I'm pretty sure I'm passing the list to the function properly, but I can't figure out why it only determines FALSE values. Any ideas?

```
def newFunction(x, y, z):
   z = 0
   if y in x:
      z = True
   else:
      z = False
   return (z)




newList = [2,4,6,8,10]
r = input ('Enter a number: ')
s = 0
newFunction(newList, r, s)
if s == True:
   print ('The no. IS in the list.')
else:
   print ('The no. IS NOT in the list.')
```

Comment: `input()` always gives string so you compare string `"2"` with number `2` and it is always false. You have to conver to `int()` - `r = int( input(... ) )`

Comment: I don’t think you’re using the result of the function either.

Comment: BTW: if you use `return z` then you should get it as `s = newFunction(list, r)`

Comment: shorter `def newFunction(x, y): return (y in x)`

Comment: Any reassignment of function parameters will not be reflected in the calling context (i.e. you can't use a function to change a value of a variable).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here:

- `input()` returns a string, so you need to convert it into an int.
- You're not doing anything with the value returned by the function.
- Related to the above, you don't need the `z` parameter in the function. Were you expecting the value of the variable outside the function to change?
- If you absolutely need to explicitly compare a value with a boolean, use `is`, not `==`. In this case, `if found:` is all you need.
- The if statement inside the function can be removed entirely.
- Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

---

A refactored version of your code would look something like this:

```py
def in_list(targ_list, elem):
    return elem in targ_list


nums_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
num_in = int(input("Enter a number: "))

res = in_list(nums_list, num_in)

print(res)

if res:
    print('The no. IS in the list.')
else:
    print('The no. IS NOT in the list.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the result of your function and convert the input to an integer for it to work.

```
def newFunction(x, y, z):
   z = 0
   if y in x:
      z = True
   else:
      z = False
   return (z)


newList = [2,4,6,8,10]
r = input ('Enter a number: ')
s = 0
found = newFunction(newList, int(r), s)
print(found)
if found == True:
   print ('The no. IS in the list.')
else:
   print ('The no. IS NOT in the list.')
```

You can also improve your current implementation by having a simpler function.

```
def newFunction(valueList, userInput):
   return userInput in valueList
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `s` - you run the function but it does not assign to `s` so change to:

```
s = newFunction(newList, r, s)
```

You can also remove the 'z' as an argument and instead return False/True in each If condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do this. Do note that the input would be type string, so you need to convert to int.

```
newList = [2,4,6,8,10]

def newFunction(x, newList):
    if x in newList:
        return True
    else:
        return False

x = int(input("Enter a number"))
if newFunction(x, newList) == True:
    print("it is in the list")
else:
    print("it is not in the list")
```

Shorter way:

```
newList = [2,4,6,8,10]

x = int(input("enter a number"))
if x in newList:
    print("it is in the list")
else:
    print("it is not in the list")
```